# Matplotlib Pie to Bae64 not displaying in HTML ( Outlook)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, outlook, base64

I am trying to display a Matplotlib Pie Chart in HTML to Outlook. It is not working. Can someone point out the error and correct. The Output pic is attached.

```
labels = 'Updated', 'Outdated'
explode = (0.0, 0.2)  # only "explode" the  slice (i.e. Updated', 'Outdated)
colors = ['Blue', 'Green', 'Red']
ServerPie= [dfServerUpdated.shape[0],dfServerOutdated.shape[0]]
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,4))


ax1.pie(ServerPie, explode=explode, labels=labels, 
        shadow=True, startangle=680,counterclock=False,labeldistance= 1.2,autopct='%.2f',radius=1.5,rotatelabels = False)  #autopct converts the values in terms of percentages and plots it in the pie chart.
ax1.axis('equal')  # Equal aspect ratio ensures that pie is drawn as a circle.

ax1.set_title("Servers Compliance ")
fname = BytesIO()
fname= 'image1.png'
plt.savefig(fname, dpi=None, facecolor='w', edgecolor='w',
        orientation='portrait', papertype=None, format=None,
        transparent=False, bbox_inches="tight", pad_inches=0,
        frameon=True)
#fname.seek(0)

fig = plt.figure()
#plot sth

tmpfile = BytesIO()
fig.savefig(tmpfile, format='png')
encoded = base64.b64encode(tmpfile.getvalue())


#encoded = base64.b64encode(fname.getvalue())
#print(encoded)
html2 = '<html><head><body>' + '<img src=\'data:image/png;base64,{}\'>'.format(encoded) + '</body></html>'
```

[image: While the Picture is missing , it is inserted]
[image: Actual Pie Chart]

Is it possible to get the pie chart to HTML working ?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook (whcih uses Word to render the HTML messages) does not support inline images where the data stored in the `src='data:image'` attribute.
You need to add the image as an attachment, set its `Content-ID` MIME attribute, then refer to that attachment in the HTML body through the content-id: `<image src='cid:xyz'>` where `"xyz"` is the value of the `Content-ID` MIME attribute of the attachment.

Comment: Kindly share any documentation or link for the same

Comment: Documentation about what? Outlook inability to display images with embedded into img tag data? Or creating messages with attachments?

Comment: Ok, I will try your suggestion. Thanks for help.